# GNU parallel nesting

Tags: gnu-parallel

I have a directory of 130000+ `.tif` files. I want to use `find` with `GNU parallel`. All my files are named in the pattern and sequence of k-001 to k-163. One of the challenges is matching `001` with `seq 1`.

I tried this:

```
seq 111 163 | parallel -j10 find . -name 'k-{}\*' -print0 | parallel -0 'tesseract {/} /mnt/ramdisk/output/{/.} > /dev/null 2>&1'
```

I am not getting parallelism from the `seq` part. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the actual issue is, but you can generate zero-padding like this if that is the problem:

```
printf "%03d\n" {0..10} | parallel -k echo
000
001
002
003
004
005
006
007
008
009
010
```

Comment: I have learnt a lot from you. So grateful. What is the rule about number of CPU cores and number of jobs? I am running into problems when I raise the number of jobs but the default job count (4 on my machine) is too low for my volume of data.

Comment: By default, **GNU Parallel** will run one job per CPU core that it detects - check with `parallel --number-of-cores`. You can change the degree of parallelism using `-j`. So, if you use `-j 32` it will run 32 jobs at a time. Or you can specify as a percentage, with `-j 200%` which will run twice as many jobs as you have cores at a time. HTH. Else have a read through the copious examples here... https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Comment: If you _really_ want to run a lot of jobs in parallel: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Running-more-than-250-jobs-workaround